# x86-64 Assembly - Sum of multiples of 3 or 5

Tags: programming-challenge, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn some basic x86 assembly and so I've begun solving Project Euler problems. I was hoping for some critique of my code that, hopefully, includes either the efficiency of the operations or the readability / style of the code itself. I will provide the Makefile for Linux 64 bit.

The purpose of the code is to sum all numbers from [0, 1000) that are divisible by 3 or 5.

The code can be run using `make RUN=euler_1`.

NB:

I am aware that most compilers replace modulos of known numbers with some combination of `mov` and `shr` to avoid the integer division. For example, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo).

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: clean

all:    $(RUN).elf
    ./$^

%.elf:  %.o 
    ld $^ -o $@ -lc -e main -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

%.o:    %.asm
    nasm -f elf64 $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.elf
```

**euler_1.asm**

```
extern printf
global main

section .data
fmt: db "%d", 0x0a, 0

section .text
    
;; main - Calculate the sum of all numbers between [0, 1000) that are divisible
;; by 3 or 5.
;;  sum : R8
main:   
    ; sum = 0
    mov r8, 0   
    ; for i in [0, 1000) {
    mov rcx, 0
for0:   
    ; if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 {

    ; i % 3 == 0
    mov rax, rcx
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r9, 3
    div r9
    test rdx, rdx
    jne if01
    ; sum = sum + i
    add r8, rcx
    jmp if0

if01:
    ; i % 5 == 0
    mov rax, rcx
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r9, 5
    div r9
    test rdx, rdx
    jne if0
    ; sum = sum + i
    add r8, rcx
    jmp if0
    ; }
if0:
    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 1000
    jl  for0
    ; }
    
    ; printf("%d", sum)
    lea rdi, [rel fmt]
    mov rsi, r8
    mov rax, 0
    call printf
    
    ; sys_exit(0)
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

Comment: I also asked about Project Euler 1 in x86_64 (but AT&T rather than Intel syntax) recently, maybe some of those comments will help you: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245990/195637

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.  The other review made some good points, but here are some not covered there.

### Decide whether you're using stdlib or not

The `Makefile` and call to `printf` both indicate that you're using the standard C library, which is fine, but then the program terminates using a `syscall` which is not.  The reason is that the standard C startup sets things up before `main` is called and then also tears them down again after `main` returns.  This code is skipping the teardown by instead using the `syscall` to end the program, which is not good practice.  There are two alternatives: either don't use the C library at all (that is, write your own [printing routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594297/how-to-print-a-string-to-the-terminal-in-x86-64-assembly-nasm-without-syscall)) or let the teardown actually happen:

```
xor eax, eax    ; set exit code to 0 to indicate success
ret             ; return to _libc_start_main which called our main
```

For further reading on how the startup and teardown works in Linux [read this](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html).

### Manage registers carefully

One of the things that expert assembly language programmers (and good compilers) do is managing register usage.  In this case, the ultimate use of the sum is to print it, and to print it we need the value in the `rsi` register.  So why not use `rsi` instead of `r8` as the running sum?

### Know how to efficiently zero a register

Obviously, if we write `mov r8, 0` it has the desired effect of loading the value 0 into the `r8` register, and as the other review notes, there are better ways to do that, but let's look more deeply.  The code currently does this:

```
; sum = 0
mov r8, 0   
; for i in [0, 1000) {
mov rcx, 0
```

That works, but let's look at the listing file to see what NASM has turned that into:

```
13                                      ; sum = 0
14 00000000 41B800000000                mov r8, 0   
15                                      ; for i in [0, 1000) {
16 00000006 B900000000                  mov rcx, 0
```

The first column is just the line number of the listing file, the second is the address and the third is the encoded instruction.  So we see that the two instructions use 11 bytes.  We can do better!  The other review correctly mentioned the `xor` instruction, so let's try it:

```
19 00000000 4D31C0                          xor     r8, r8
20 00000003 4831C9                          xor     rcx, rcx
```

Better, only six bytes.  We can do better still.  As one of the comments correctly noted, on a 64-bit x86 machine, if you `xor` the lower half of a `rXX` register, it also clears the upper half.  So let's do that:

```
19 00000000 4D31C0                          xor     r8, r8
20 00000003 31C9                            xor     ecx, ecx
```

That saved one byte, but there is no `e8` register.  Can we do better by clearing `ecx` and then copying that value into `r8`?

```
14 00000000 31C9                            xor     ecx, ecx
20 00000002 4989C8                          mov     r8, rcx
```

No, we can't, unless we also follow the advice above and use `rsi` instead of `r8`:

```
19 00000000 31C9                            xor     ecx, ecx
20 00000002 31F6                            xor     esi, esi
```

Now we're down to four bytes, and we no longer need the `mov rsi, r8` instruction which saves us another 3 bytes, for a net savings of 10 bytes with just those two things.

### Avoid `div` if practical

The `div` instruction is one of the slowest instructions on the x86_64 architecture and can also cause an exception if we try to divide by zero.  For both of those reasons, it's often better to avoid the instruction if we can.  In this case, one way to avoid it is to note that it looks a lot like [`fizzbuzz`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56896/39848) and keep two counters: one that counts down from 5 and the other that counts down from 3.

### Use local labels where practical

It's clear that `main` needs to be a file global symbol, but `for0` and `if01` (both poor names, as has already been noted) do not need to be.  In NASM, we can designate [local labels](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9) by prefixing those labels with a single period so instead of `for0` we could use `.for0`.  The advantage to doing this is that we can reuse a label in another function without having to worry about collision.

### Avoid unconditional jumps where practical

The x86 processor does its best to figure out which instruction will be executed next.  It has all kinds of things to make that happen, including multi-level cacheing and branch prediction.  It does that to try to make software run faster.  You can help it by avoiding branching at all where practical, and especially by avoiding unconditional jumps.  Thinking carefully about it, we can often do this by restructuring the code.  Here's the original code:

```
        test rdx, rdx
        jne if01
        ; sum = sum + i
        add rsi, rcx
        jmp if0

if01:
        ; i % 5 == 0
        mov rax, rcx
        mov rdx, 0
        mov r9, 5
        div r9
        test rdx, rdx
        jne if0
        ; sum = sum + i
        add rsi, rcx
        jmp if0
        ; }
if0:
        inc rcx
        cmp rcx, 1000
        jl  for0
```

We can rewrite this like this:

```
        test rdx, rdx
        je  .accumulate
        ; i % 5 == 0
        mov rax, rcx
        mov rdx, 0
        mov r9, 5
        div r9
        test rdx, rdx
        jne .next
.accumulate:
        ; sum = sum + i
        add rsi, rcx
        ; }
.next:
        inc rcx
        cmp rcx, 1000
        jl  .for0
```

Comment: Unconditional jumps aren't necessarily bad. In fact, they're more likely to be predicted properly than conditional jumps. But in this case, you are exactly right, the code should be restructured to simply fall through. In general, a good rule of thumb is that the expected case should be the fall-through case, and the unexpected case should be the one that takes a branch. When writing large swaths of assembly code,  readability and performance concerns dovetail nicely: avoid as many branches as reasonably possible.

Comment: I wonder if it might be worthwhile to use `cmov` instructions to avoid having a branch at all in that part of the code.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: That is a very good suggestion.

Comment: Regarding "there is no `e8` register": I thought that was what `r8d` would be.  (However, in my test with GNU asm, `xor %r8, %r8` and `xor %r8d, %r8d` ended up having the same length.)

Comment: The Q&A you linked about the `write` syscall only covers strings.  To also / instead cover formatting integers into strings of decimal digits, [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) is NASM for x86-64 Linux.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: You're correct, the 32-bit version of `r8` is `r8d`.  It doesn't make xor-zeroing smaller because it still needs a REX prefix for the register number.  But you should still use `xor r8d, r8d` because Silvermont doesn't recognize `xor r8,r8` as a "zeroing idiom" independent of the old value, but 32-bit operand-size xor   (which all compilers always use) is optimal on every CPU that treats any kind of zeroing idiom specially. See [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)

Answer (score 16):

- `if01` and `if0` are not the greatest names.
- Instead of reloading `r9`, use two registers. Let `r9` always contain 3, and `r10` always contain 5.
- Increment `r8` in one place.
- Running the loop downwards (1000 to 0), rather than upwards, spares an instruction (`cmp`).
- `mov rdx, 0` is encoded in 7  bytes. `xor rdx, rdx` is way shorter.

All that said, consider

```
main:
    mov r8, 0   
    mov r9, 3
    mov r10, 5

    ; for i in (1000, 0] 
    mov rcx, 999

for0:   
    mov rax, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx
    div r9
    test rdx, rdx
    jeq accumulate

    mov rax, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx
    div r10
    test rdx, rdx
    jne next

accumulate:
    add r8, rcx
next:
    dec rcx
    jne  for0
```

PS: I hope you know that this problem has a very straightforward arithmetical solution.

Comment: +1 for the final comment especially.

Comment: What assembler uses the mnemonic `jeq`? Or is that just a typo? Also, you do not need to use the full 64-bit registers when clearing or loading small immediates. The upper 32 bits are automatically cleared, so you can just do, e.g., `xor edx, edx`. And there's never a reason to do `mov reg, 0`.

Comment: @CodyGray if you wanted to align the next instruction, I suppose `mov reg32,0` could be (if it has a suitable size) a better choice than `xor reg32,reg32\nnop dword [rax]`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, there are times you might intentionally want to use a larger-size instruction for alignment reasons. But the only time you would worry about that sort of alignment is before a branch target, when that branch was expected to be taken a large number of times. And honestly, whether the MOV vs the XOR+NOP is better, I couldn't tell you. You'd have to benchmark it. Most of the benchmarks I've run tell me that alignment is not obsessing over. The assembler should automatically align functions. @Ruslan

Comment: @CodyGray: Compilers automatically align functions.  In hand-written assembly, you should use `align 16` before labels if you want to match that behaviour.  If I wanted a longer zeroing instruction, I might use some dummy segment-override prefixes and a REX.W=0 before a 32-bit xor-zeroing instruction.  Segment prefixes (unlike REP) can apply to some forms of XOR, so it's highly unlikely that future CPUs will use that prefix+opcode combo as some other instruction.

Comment: If I didn't want to use extra prefixes on xor-zeroing, `mov reg, 0` is really not bad unless you need to avoid partial-register penalties on P6-family (e.g. before setcc); I think I mentioned that in my canonical answer on [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617). Modern CPUs have enough back-end ports vs. their front-end width that having xor-zeroing eliminated is usually not significant for throughput.  And only Intel actually eliminates it in the front-end; AMD Zen only eliminates `mov reg,reg`.  (@Ruslan)

Comment: Besides xor-zeroing, we know the remainder of anything divided by 3 or 5 will fit in a 32-bit register, so we can similarly save a REX prefix with `test edx, edx`.  (And with `mov r9d, 3`, although [NASM will do that optimization for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly) because it's exactly equivalent.  Other assemblers won't, and understanding x86-64's implicit zero-extending is important for understanding some compiler-generated code because they always optimize mov-immediate; unfortunately not always other insns.)

Answer (score 11):

A few quick notes on your implementation choices, and how I'd approach it:

You don't need 64-bit operand-size for `div` when your numbers only go up to 1000, that's significantly slower than `div r32` on Intel before Ice Lake: I explained the details in another Code Review: [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204902/checking-if-a-number-is-prime-in-nasm-win64-assembly/204965#204965).

(And in general for other instructions, `test edx, edx` would save code size there. Even with 64-bit numbers and 64-bit `div`, `i % 5` will always fit in 32 bits so it's safe to ignore the high 32.  See
[The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64) - it's the default operand-size for x86-64, not needing any machine-code prefixes.  For efficiency, use it unless you actually need 64-bit operand-size for that specific instruction, and implicit zero-extension to 64-bit won't do what you need.
Don't spend extra instructions, though; 64-bit operand-size is often needed, e.g. for pointer increments.)

Of course, for division by compile-time constants, `div` is a slow option that compilers avoid entirely, instead using a fixed-point multiplicative inverse.  Like in [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi) on SO, or [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142842/integer-to-ascii-algorithm-x86-assembly).

---

Also, you don't need to divide at all if you use down-counters that you reset to 3 or 5 when they hit 0 (and/or unrolling) to handle the 3, 5 pattern, like FizzBuzz - see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334034/fizzbuzz-in-assembly-segmentation-fault/37494090#37494090) where I wrote a large tutorial about such techniques, which I won't repeat here.  Unlike FizzBuzz, you only want to count a number once even if it's a multiple of both 3 and 5.

You could just unroll by 15 (so the pattern fully repeats) and hard-code something like

```
.unroll15_loop:
                                    ; lets say ECX=60 for example
    add  eax, ecx                   ; += 60
    lea  eax, [rax + rcx + 3]       ; += 63
    lea  eax, [rax + rcx + 5]       ; += 65
    lea  eax, [rax + rcx + 6]       ; += 66
    ...
    add  ecx, 15
    cmp  ecx, 1000-15
    jbe  .unroll15_loop
   ; handle the last not full group of 15 numbers
```

Or apply some math and instead of actually looking at every number, use a closed-form formula for the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 in a 15-number range, offset by `i * nmuls` where `i` is the start of your range, and `nmuls` is the number of multiples.

e.g. in the `[60, 75)` range, we have 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72.  So that's 8 of the 15 numbers.  So it's like `[0, 15)` but `+ 8*60`.  Either do the 0..14 part by hand, or with a loop and remember the result.  (Project Euler is about math as much as programming; it's up to you how much math you want to do vs. how much brute force you want your program to do.)

Conveniently, 8 happens to be one of the scale-factors that x86 addressing modes support, so we can even do

```
lea eax, [rax + rcx*8 + 0 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12]
```

(3+5+6+... is a constant expression so the assembler can do it for you at assemble time, producing a `[reg + reg*scale + disp8]` addressing mode.  Unfortunately that 3-component LEA has 3-cycle latency on Intel CPUs, and that loop-carried dependency will be the bottleneck for the loop.  So it would actually be more efficient to use a separate `add` instruction.)

And of course we've reduced this to basically a sum of a linearly increasing series, and could apply Gauss's formula (`n * (n+1) / 2`) for a closed form over the whole-interval range, just having to handle the cleanup of `n%15` for the numbers approaching `n`.  BTW, clang knows how to turn a simple for loop doing `sum += i;` into the closed form, arranging it to avoid overflow of the temporary before dividing by 2. (right shift).  Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) uses that as an example.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output

Comment: The remainder part could be implemented based on a simple table lookup.  Especially if you're doing a count down to 0; but even if you're doing a count up to the limit, you could have the table with entries for the number of multiples of the base and the constant term to use.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Oh, the 0..14 elements of cleanup?  Yeah, might as well just look up the answer instead of a jump table into a series of `lea` and NOP instructions or something.  Although if you make every LEA the same length, you can do a computed jump (like `end_of_block - remaining * 4` instead of loading from a table of pointers, so no static data involved.  That might be fun, but yeah the efficient option would be a table.

Answer (score 4):

## Use conditional move instructions where appropriate

To extend the discussion in [the answer by @Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253707/232026): if you can use conditional move instructions, that will further reduce the amount of branching and thus help the processor.

If you combine with the suggestion to maintain modulo 3 and modulo 5 counters instead of doing division, then an outline of the main loop body could look like this (untested, though):

```
%define mod3_reg r8
%define mod5_reg r9
%define zero_reg r10
%define count_reg rcx
%define accum_reg rsi
%define addend_reg rdi
%define limit 1000

    ...
mainloop:
    xor addend_reg, addend_reg
    inc mod3_reg
    cmp mod3_reg, 3
    cmove addend_reg, count_reg
    cmove mod3_reg, zero_reg
    inc mod5_reg
    cmp mod5_reg, 5
    cmove addend_reg, count_reg
    cmove mod5_reg, zero_reg
    add accum_reg, addend_reg

    inc count_reg
    cmp count_reg, limit
    jl mainloop
```

(Note that in order to match an initial value of 0 for the counter, you would need to initialize `mod3_reg` to 2 and `mod5_reg` to 4.  If you adjust to start with 1, on the other hand, you could initialize both to 0 which would be a bit simpler.)

---

Do also note that according to some comments by @PeterCordes, there may be issues with `cmov` creating enough extra dependencies in the loop that it might not actually turn out to be worth it.  This would be a case where, if you cared a lot about performance, running a benchmark on your target machine would be important.

Comment: Instead of `inc`, `cmp` it would be simpler and shorter to preload with 3 and 5 and count down with `dec`.  You could then directly use `cmove` to reload.

Comment: Sure, that's definitely a possibility.  Then, you could take advantage of the fact that `dec` preloads flags for you and avoid the `test` or `cmp`.  In the end, I ended up doing it this way for a slight improvement in readability - with the count down, it's a bit more complex to describe what the registers represent.

Comment: If you're going for simplicity not performance, you can increment your mod3 and mod5 regs *after* their cmp/cmov (next to count_reg), so everything can start at zero.  Or with down-counters, they'd just start at 3 and 5 for counter=0, same as their reset values.

Comment: However, this branchless strategy is probably only good for *very* low limits; Most modern branch predictors will learn the pattern quickly.  But you're always paying a high cost every time through the loop for front-end throughput (12 uops assuming single-uop CMOVE (Intel Broadwell and later, or AMD since forever) and macro-fusion of cmp/jl, so on a 4-wide pipeline like Intel before Ice Lake, that takes 3 cycles per iteration to issue.  With down-counters, that could get down to 10 uops, which Zen can issue in 2 cycles.

Comment: Then you're up against the 2-cycle loop-carried dependency chain you've created with inc/cmov on the mod3 and 5 counters.  (Or worse, 3-cycle on older Intel with 2-uop cmov).  Out-of-order exec can hide some of that if the loop trip count is low and the code after doesn't all depend on the result.  But otherwise (for 1k iters) some branch misses early will pay for themselves overall. At least the dep chain through the accum_reg itself is only 1 cycle. (GCC [sometimes pessimizes branchless C](//stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) to make cmov part of longer dep chains, like prepare 2 possible vals.)

Comment: And BTW, you don't need to use 64-bit operand-size for the counters; edx and edi would be fine for the mod counters, allowing those insns to avoid REX prefixes, even if you did want to run this for a limit too large to fit in ECX.  The mod regs could even be 8-bit so you can increment or decrement them both at once, except then you can't use 8-bit cmov and partial regs suck.  (Chris Jester-Young suggested that in [16-bit FizzBuzz in x86 NASM assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56896) where it's specifically useful to know when both counters become zero at once)

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I've added a section at the tail acknowledging that benchmarking would be important if you want to see whether the change to `cmov` actually helps or hurts overall performance.